# Typescript Map with different value based on key type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Is it possible to create a `Map` in TS that returns a different value type depending on the key type? Here's the equivalent with `Record`.

```js
interface Section {
  variableName: string
}

interface Field {
  displayText: string
}

const specialKey = Symbol('This is the key to sections')

type Foo = {[specialKey]: Section} & Record<string, Field> 

const foo: Foo = {
  [specialKey]: {
    variableName: 'heh'
  },
  other: {
    displayText: 'sure'
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGVXJm) might work for you; see the answer to the linked question for more information

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is an example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQWYB7EyDeAsAFDLIBucUwcARgDYQBycAthAFzIDOY1IAcxIBfEiVCRYiFADFgEegBMCJMouDcADvTgBPACoQAHmC69+Q4qOIkEuXj00Ya9ANIRdyALxpdrWtj0ABQA5PoAFhrIUWDhKADWHshg2DwYWPYhAJRixGC6Tsgy2NgAPK7eyIm62DBo6TggAHyVFcaQIIrcVR619ZiNyAD8BMgA2lrOcG4eALpcAEoY2FCK5QA0-RkgY66zLcLIAGTIS3arpeagAptyCootXCAQ5NC5diAOMCVcxak+RFI40mCBc7l08xUQLIlGodEYLHYXBCcXCIVUyGE6wx2Fi0C4gLIag02j0hhMyO4AFcoBB0UDrMIgA

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic I think @jcalz version is what I'm looking for. The example in the question already handles the conditional type correctly for `Record`.